# Sitecore EXM unsubscribe link

Tags: sitecore8

We are using Sitecore 8.2 update 1 and relevant exm module. I'm using the unsubscribe link in my exm template. (Copied the url from
default one-column message template. /sitecore/Unsubscribe.aspx).

But in the delivered email, when I click the "Unsubscribe" link, I'm getting redirected to 404 (page not found).

I checked the "Analytics.ClusterName" setting Its pointing correctly to my cd hostname. But still we are facing this error. Any clue on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Which EXM version are you using?

if EXM 3.5 you have to use sitecore modules/Web/EXM/Unsubscribe.aspx

if EXM 3.4 (or less) you have to use /sitecore/Unsubscribe.aspx